# Error: cannot add csv to Java array using lombok

Tags: java, arrays, collections, lombok

I am trying to add the data from an existing csv file to a java array but I don 't seem to find a way around it.

Here is the error I'm having after multiple tries.
error: cannot assign a value to final variable addPlatform
addPlatform = new ArrayList();

Here is my main.java

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game("platforms.csv");
        game.run();
    }

@Getter(lazy = true)
    private final List<Platform> addPlatform = new ArrayList<Platform>();
    /**
     * Reads platforms from csv file and returns the as list.
     * @return platforms - Platforms as list
     */
    private List<Platform> readPlatforms() {
        if (addPlatform == null) {
            addPlatform = new ArrayList<Platform>();
        }

        return addPlatform;

    }
```

platform.java

```
package com.nortal.platformer;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class Platform {

    private Integer index;
    private Integer cost;
}
```

platform.csv

```
index, cost
0, 100
1, 200
2, 400
```

Comment: I have a class Game.java and I have a file platforms.csv. I am trying to add all the rows in the csv file to a list (in Game.java)

```
/**
     * Reads platforms from csv file and returns them as list.
     * @return platforms - Platforms as list
     */
    private List<Platform> readPlatforms() {


        return addPlatform;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`final` variables cannot be assigned new value. The values are only assigned in either during declaration or in constructor.

Change your class like:

If you need to assign value to `addPlatform` then, it cannot be final - which means, you've to remove `lazy=true` and implement your own lazy initialization without `final`.

Simplest implementation is

```
    private List<Platform> addPlatform;

    public synchronized List<Platform> getAddPlatform(){
        if (addPlatform == null) {
            addPlatform = new ArrayList<Platform>();
        }

        return addPlatform;
    }
```

Comment: This is the error I get:

error: not a statement
        this.addPlatform;

Comment: The error explains itself. By design, `final` variables cannot be "re-assigned" once created.

Comment: Still got some errors, Index 0 out of bounds for length 0. Let me explain what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to add the values in the csv files to a list then return the values in the list but it isn't currently working

Comment: The question is unclear - please provide a minimal reproducible code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have a class Game.java and I have a file platforms.csv. I am trying to add all the rows in the csv file to a list (in Game.java)

```
/**
     * Reads platforms from csv file and returns them as list.
     * @return platforms - Platforms as list
     */
    private List<Platform> readPlatforms() {


        return addPlatform;

    }
```

Comment: @dMd I have the impression you're a Java novice. My advise is to start reading some java books or doing some online trainings before posting more questions to stackoverflow. That will give you a better understanding of the programming concepts, instead of just getting someone to fix your program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case it twofold:

- In readPlatform you're creating a new ArrayList, and try to assign it to a final field
- If you're using `@Getter(lazy=true)`, lombok will generate an entirely different datastructure, so the type of the `addPlatform` is no longer `List<Platform>`

I do not know why in this case you're using a lazy getter, since the initialization code is neither expensive to calculate nor does it use a lot of memory. So in your case I would write:

```java
@Getter
final private List<Platform> = new ArrayList<>();
```

Accessing final fields themselves is always threadsafe.

But since you're also using `synchonized` in your code, I think you shouldn't be using an `ArrayList`, but probably a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

```java
@Getter
final private List<Platform> = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Fields annotated with lombok's `@Getter(lazy=true)` have to be final, and that allows lombok to rewrite the whole underlying code. The only supported way to get the contents is via the getter. Also, lazy getters do have their own thread safety built in. So no need for the whole synchronized block.

Disclosure: I am a Project Lombok developer.